# VSCode empty nested quotation mark strings in configurations stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04, quotation-marks, vscode-tasks

I use Visual Studio Code latest stable version and I had configuration like:

```
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/debug/bin/something-wallet-rpc",
    "args": [
        "--rpc-bind-port", "19835",
        "--wallet-file", "wallet",
        "--password", "\"\"",
        "--log-level", "2"
    ],
```

and it has been working well, but sudddenly the line `"--password", "\"\"",` is getting passed incorrectly to Ubuntu terminal and I get an error with incorrect password.

But when I open terminal and use `./build/debug/bin/something-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 19835 --wallet-file wallet --password "" --log-level 2`, it works correctly.

What can be the problem and how to fix/workaround my configuration?
Debugging is very hard without this.

Comment: You can debug it by using "program": "echo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Visual Studio Code, so solution is to downgrade or update version.